# Formula to calculate number of combinations with constraints?

Tags: combinatorics

A team consists of two unique players.
A match consists of two teams. Players must be unique within a match.

Case 1:
If I have $n$ players, what is the number of unique match combinations for those $n$ players? $n$ is a multiple of 4.

Case 2 (with constraint).
Players are divided equally into two groups A and B.
The constraint is that a team must be composed of a player belonging to Group A and a player belonging to group B. How to calculate the number of unique matches?

Thank you!

- EDIT *

Was just able to calculate the unique number of matches for Case 1.

The formula I came up with is:

$((n(n-1)/2) * (y(y-1)/2) ) /2$

where $y = n-2$

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I am able to calculate the number of unique team combinations, with the formula:
formula is n(n-1)/2.

But I have not figured out how to calculate the unique number of matches

This is for Case 1. Without constraint

Comment: Let $a$= number of players in group A and same for $b$. We need to select a team : $a \times b$ possibilities. With the remaining players, we need to select another team : $(a-1) \times (b-1)$. And the match (x,y)(z,t) or (z,t)(x,y) has been counted twice, so final result is $a \times b \times (a-1)\times (b-1)/2$

Comment: @Lourrran: That's more an answer than a comment.

Comment: @Lourrran thank you, that is what I was needing!! You should add it an as answer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a=$ number of players in group A and same for $b$.

We need to select a team : $a \times b$ possibilities. With the remaining players, we need to select another team : $(a−1) \times (b−1)$.

And the match (x,y)(z,t) or (z,t)(x,y) has been counted twice, so final result is $\frac{a \times b \times (a−1) \times (b−1)}{2}$

Edit : when we are a beginner in this discipline, we need to check if the result is correct, for some obvious values.

If $a=0$ or $a=1$, it is obvious that there is no solution. And the formula gives : number of solutions = 0 ; Good !

We need to check results not only when we are a beginner ; in real life, people who always check are advanced or experts.